# Changing label height property dynamically

Tags: html, asp.net, properties

I have a line of code:

```
Label11.Style["Height"] = (Label11.Height.Value + 15).ToString() + "px";
```

I populate the Label with text, each time I'm doing it I would like to increase the height of the Label by 15 px.

After the first populate it works fine (Height = 30), but after that it didn't change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you updating Height after postback ? Can you use jQuery for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to find the solution:

```
Label11.Height = new Unit((int)Label11.Height.Value + 15);
```